# ORDER BY part string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a column name `unique` and Im trying to print results ordered randomly, first all the rows which starts with `lead_` and then all the rest of the rows.

For example if I have this rows:

```
abc
lead_ass
dsff
dds
lead_fdg
fds
lead_hhf
```

I need to first print `lead_ass,lead_fdg,lead_nhf` ordered randomly and then all the rest, also ordered randomly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this as:

```
order by (col like 'lead_%') desc,
         rand()
```

The expression `(col like 'lead_%')` returns either true (treated as 1) or false (treated as 0), so the `desc` puts the matches first.  The `rand()` is just because you say you want things ordered randomly.  This will order both groups randomly.

Comment: you did beat me by 2 seconds :D +1

Comment: Thank you! but there is a way to make the `lead_` also ordered randomly?

Comment: @OfirH . . . This will order both groups randomly, those that start with `'lead_'` and those that don't.

Comment: @GordonLinoff as you say in your answer `(col like 'lead_%')` will return 1 if true and then I use `DESC` to print them first. `DESC` if the number is equal is random?

Comment: @OfirH . . . No, the `rand()` randomizes the results in each group.  It is the second sort key.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know it the second sort key. so it should sort all fields which dosen't strats with `lead_` randomly. But I guess I got my answer because if I understood correct the rand() refeerring to all order groups. Thany you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CASE` and `LEFT` function

```
ORDER BY CASE 
         WHEN LEFT(col,5) ='lead_' 
         THEN 1 ELSE 2
         END
```